# Is it possible to wear many hats

Tags: discussion, winterbash

I apologize if the answer was supposed to be obvious, but I didn't see anything on the topic and I am curious.

The winter bash hats are pretty neat and there's lots of different ones.  Is there a way to display more than one at a time?  I suppose too many would hide the icon, but a few might work quite well.  It looks like they're just layered on top of the icon picture, and I don't know if it would cause problems to have more than one layer at a time, or if there might be a different way of adding many hats.

I would be pleased with either a way make it work, or a reason why it doesn't (or shouldn't).

Comment: Although it doesn’t achieve the effect you’re going for, you can wear different hats on different Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Alas no](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159307/how-about-multiple-hats); not within the SE interface, anyway. However, in an answer to the question I just linked to, Aarthi (a former SE employee) mentions the one way you *can*, sort of, do this:

> That said, there's a fairly easy "cheat" around this -- just screencap your gravatar wearing a hat, make that image your gravatar, and equip a different hat. repeat until you are wearing all the hats!

For example, consider [Mike Edenfield](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2816/mike-edenfield?tab=profile). He appears to be wearing both Timey-Wimey and A New Hope:

[image]

But if you look at his [actual avatar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p84Q9.png?s=328&g=1), you will see that he just took a screenshot of Cthulhu wearing the Timey-Wimey hat, and uploaded that as his new avatar:

[image]

The main limitation here is that any hats that are part of your screencap won't be able to extend beyond the regular avatar boundaries the way overlain hats can (my Fan-hat-tic hat, for example)

Comment: Most excellent - I'm having fun with this!